# Is there an alternative way to install python library if I keep getting errors and can't resolve them?

Tags: python, pip

Recently I've been getting various errors when installing libraries some related to compiling and others that are not. I tried fixing that but to no success. So is there any other way to install python library if I get errors when installing and/or don't want to fix compiler dependencies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: This question has been asked here literally *hundreds* of times, if not thousands by now (I've lost count). There is no need for another one pointing to Gohlke's repository. Please search before asking questions.

Comment: @mattdmo I'm not looking to solve that specific error, just providing it as example to deliver the answer. People that don't have that specific error may not even find the answer. Also there aren't any easy to find sources that point to wheel for times when usual installation fails. So the question isn't how to solve that **specific error** it's what alternative ways there are to install library when everything else fails.

Comment: As I said, variations of that question ("*How do I install module X because it requires a compiler?*") has been asked far too many times (I've answered a number myself) - look to your right at the **Related** column for a few examples. If you'd read the answers to the question I linked to, you'll find many different solutions of varying utility, **including** using Gohlke's repository. Therefore, this is a duplicate. I appreciate your effort, but if you want to meaningfully contribute you should read the *entire* [help] carefully and do your background research to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes there is, my friend. The first thing you'll have to do is `pip install wheel` if it's not installed already. Then [go here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), find the library you're interested in and download .whl package that fits your system and python version. Now all that's left is to `pip install c:\example\path\Kivy-1.9.0-cp34-none-win32.whl`. So far this has solved every error I had when installing libraries.

Few notes:

1. Don't change the name of the .whl file as details contained in it are required for installation;
2. Avoid using paths that contain spaces in it as without proper escaping it may not work.
3. Don't forget that you're now forever in debt to people who made that site, I hope it saves your ass as many times as it saved mine.

Comment: #2 is irrelevant. If your OS supports spaces in paths (as all modern ones do), then you can use them. You just need to **properly** escape them or quote the entire path. There's no magic to it...

Comment: @MattDMo changed accordingly.